# Aurelia class.bind does not trigger function

Tags: aurelia

I have an Aurelia View as follows:

```
<li repeat.for="pageNumber of numOfPages">
   <a class.bind="isCurrentPage(pageNumber) ? 'blueBackground' :''" click.delegate="pageClicked(pageNumber)">
      ${pageNumber}
   </a>
</li>
```

and the model as follows:

```
pageClicked(pageNumber: number) {
    this.currentPage = pageNumber;
}


isCurrentPage(pageNumber: number) {
    return this.currentPage === pageNumber;
}
```

It works only for the first `a` element and adds the `bluBackground` class for it. But when I click on any other `a` element, it doesn't fire the `isCurrentPage` method, so the class is not updated.

However, when I replace the condition as follows:

```
<li repeat.for="pageNumber of numOfPages">
    <a class="page-link" class.bind="pageNumber === currentPage ? 'blueBackground' : ''" click.delegate="pageClicked(pageNumber)">
    ${pageNumber}
    </a>
</li>
```

It works fine and `blueBackground` class is added on each `a` which was clicked.

My question is, what's the difference in executing a code in `class.bind` like

1. `isCurrentPage(pageNumber)` and
2. `pageNumber === currentPage`

   and why is the function `isCurrentPage(pageNumber)` not called every time in the first case? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that in the first example since `pageNumber` never changes, it doesn't cause the binding to update, however, in the second example, when you click it sets `currentPage` equal to `pageNumber`. Changing `currentPage` causes the binding to update.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my original question, but I have updated the surrounding tag for `<a>` element. It is part of a `<li>` tag  which loops over and `pageNumber` takes different values..Hope this is clear.

Comment: Yes, it does change `pageNumber` per `<li>`, however, each `<li>` element keeps track of its `pageNumber` which never changes in its `class.bind`. Calling `pageClicked` with its `pageNumber` won't cause `class.bind` to update because `class.bind` doesn't watch `currentPage`. `class.bind` is going to call `isCurrentPage(pageNumber)` only if `pageNumber` value changed. It never changes once initially assigned. However, the second example does listen to `currentPage` so when the click event changes it, `class.bind` updates.

Comment: That makes sense. What do you mean by 
1. `Calling pageClicked with its pageNumber won't cause class.bind to update because class.bind doesn't watch currentPage`
2. `the second example does listen to currentPage`

Comment: What determines if a binding is watching a particular variable?

Comment: Example 2 does watch `currentPage` and updates with the click, as you noticed. Example 1 does not watch `currentPage` even though it's being changed in the click as well. The property needs to be part of the binding expression in order to be watched. `class.bind="isCurrentPage(pageNumber)"` doesn't care about `currentPage` changing at all, but `class.bind="pageNumber === currentPage ? true : false"` watches both `pageNumber` and `currentPage` and updates when `currentPage` changes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. I didn't know that all the properties in the binding expression are being watched. Thanks.